# What is the maximum size limit of queue in C++ / what are all the factors that determine the size limit or overflow limit?

Tags: c++, queue

This is my queue implementation

```
/* structure to store the start/end time */
struct mq{
    mq() : start_time(), end_time() {}
    mq(uint32_t start_time, uint32_t end_time) : start_time(start_time), end_time(end_time) {}
    uint32_t start_time;
    uint32_t end_time;
};
mq msg;

/* queue to hold the structure  */
std::queue<mq> Mqueue;
```

The current size of the queue can be found using

```
Mqueue.size()
```

How to get the maximum size limit of the queue or how large can I have the queue without overflow or at what limit does the queue will overflow ?

Comment: My guess is that will depend on underlying `Container`. It is `std::deque` by default and its limit is [`std::deque::max_size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/max_size). (not posting as answer because this is just guess)

Comment: On a 64-bit machine, you really shouldn't need to worry about how many items you can store in your queue.  You're more likely to be restricted by the number of human lifetimes it would take to fill it, assuming you have unlimited RAM.